How to get collective error msg, dirty status,values of formik forms
return (
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} enableReinitialize validationSchema={columnDef.validation} onSubmit={() => {}}>
{({ values, handleChange, handleBlur, errors, touched, dirty, setFieldValue }) => {
console.log('dirty>>>>', dirty);
useEffect(() => {
if (errors) {
setGlobalError(errors);
}
}, [errors]);
useEffect(() => {
console.log('dirty select...', dirty, values);
setGlobalDirty(dirty);
setGlobalValues(values);
}, [dirty, values]);
// Handle rendering of input element based on column type
switch (columnDef.dataType) {
case 'text':
element = isEditable ? (
<TextField
value={values[columnDef.accessorKey]}
id={${row.index}-${columnDef.accessorKey}} // Use accessorKey for unique id
name={columnDef.accessorKey}
onChange={(e: any) => {
handleChange(e);
onChangeText(e);
}}
onBlur={handleBlur}
error={Boolean(errors[columnDef.accessorKey])}
helperText={errors[columnDef.accessorKey] && (errors[columnDef.accessorKey] as string)}
sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': { py: 0.75, px: 1 } }}
/>
) : (
value // If not editable, display the static value
);
break;
      case 'selectoperationdetails':
        element = (
          <>
            {isEditable ? (
              <>
                <Autocomplete
                  fullWidth
                  multiple
                  options={columnDef.dataOption as any}
                  open={open}
                  onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
                  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                  disableCloseOnSelect
                  isOptionEqualToValue={(option: any, value: any) => option === value}
                  getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option}
                  getOptionDisabled={(option) =>
                    option === columnDef.dataOption[0] && (value?.length || 0) > 1 && value !== columnDef.dataOption[0]
                  }
                  onChange={(e, value) => {
                    // Handle change for both the Autocomplete and Formik
                    const newValue = value.map((item) => item.trim());
                    setFieldValue(columnDef.accessorKey, newValue.join(','));

                    onChangeSelectOperation(e, newValue); // Call your custom function
                  }}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={
                    typeof value === 'string'
                      ? value.trim() === ''
                        ? [] // If the string is empty, use an empty array
                        : value.split(',').map((item) => item.trim())
                      : Array.isArray(value)
                        ? value
                        : []
                  }
                  loading={isLoading}
                  renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                    <li {...props}>
                      <Checkbox icon={icon} checkedIcon={checkedIcon} style={{ marginRight: 8 }} checked={selected} />
                      {option}
                    </li>
                  )}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Select"
                      placeholder="Select"
                      InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                          <React.Fragment>
                            {isLoading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                          </React.Fragment>
                        )
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                {errors[columnDef.accessorKey] && (
                  <FormHelperText error id="select" sx={{ pl: 1.75 }}>
                    <>
                      {typeof errors[columnDef.accessorKey] === 'string'
                        ? errors[columnDef.accessorKey]
                        : JSON.stringify(errors[columnDef.accessorKey])}
                    </>
                  </FormHelperText>
                )}
              </>
            ) : (
              <span>{Array.isArray(value) ? value.join(', ') : value}</span>
            )}
          </>
        );
        break; like these i have some independent fields(Generic) . whenever i clk the field got the error msg,dirty status for that particular field alone. Additionally i need to get the other fields errormsg and dirty status also. Here i cudnt use formikProvider or useFormikContext. Any ideas please

